# as3 embed uploaded swf into scene

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

```
 var file:FileReference=new FileReference();
```

and then

```
trace (file.data);
```

works fine

after that I'm trying to embed received data into the scene but with no success

```
var ExtSWF:MovieClip;
ExtSWF = file.data.readObject() as MovieClip;
trace(ExtSWF);
```

returns null

but if I load it as remote file, with `Loader` - it works fine

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.load(new URLRequest("ext.swf"));
......
ExtSWF = MovieClip(ldr.contentLoaderInfo.content);
```

Is it possible to just upload swf file and embed it into the scene, or `Loader` class is the only possibility to archieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Loader class is used to load SWF files or image (JPG, PNG, or GIF)
>   files.

But "load" really meaning "**decode format**" for display. So pass your `file.data` bytes through the Loader using `Loader.loadbytes` for decoding to a valid MovieClip object.

Try

```
//var ExtSWF : MovieClip = new MovieClip;
//ExtSWF = file.data.readObject() as MovieClip;
var ldr : Loader = new Loader(); //# declare outside of any functions (make as public var)
ldr.loadBytes(file.data); //#use Loader to auto-decode bytes of SWF
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_swfLoaded );
```

And also have a handler function for the decoding completion...

```
function on_swfLoaded (evt:Event) : void
{
    var ExtSWF : MovieClip = new MovieClip;
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_swfLoaded );
    ExtSWF = ldr.content as MovieClip;

    trace(ExtSWF);
    ExtSWF.x =50; ExtSWF.y = 50; addChild(ExtSWF);
}
```